# I am getting following error while runnung jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda

```
jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1358, in initialize
    super(NotebookApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-6>", line 2, in initialize
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 243, in initialize
    self.migrate_config()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 169, in migrate_config
    migrate()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\migrate.py", line 240, in migrate
    ensure_dir_exists(env['jupyter_config'])
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\ipython_genutils\path.py", line 167, in ensure_dir_exists
    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
  File "c:\python27\lib\os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "c:\python27\lib\os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "c:\python27\lib\os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "c:\python27\lib\os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "c:\python27\lib\os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "c:\python27\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\srava\\ C:'
```

Comment: Please format your text properly, and your answer is on the last line: "[Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: `'C:\Users\srava\ C:'`". You have forgotten to double-up `\ ` somewhere.

Comment: What does this have to do with Anaconda? This looks like a stock Python 2.7 install. Maybe that's part of the problem?